# "remain a problem / an issue" vs "stay a problem / an issue"

Tags: difference

**(1)** to remain a problem / an issue – I know it’s a correct phrase
**(2)** to stay a problem / an issue – I don't know if it’s correct

So, is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what is the difference between (1) and (2)?

---

A-variants below were taken from the internet.
B-variants are my own.

**(3a)** She indicated that she had asked herself this question as a student but even years after it still **remained** an issue for her.
**(3b)** She indicated that she had asked herself this question as a student but even years after it still **stayed** an issue for her.

**(4a)** Poverty still **remains** an issue to be reckoned with in the South Asian context.
**(4b)** Poverty still **stays** an issue to be reckoned with in the South Asian context.

**(5a)** Health care costs will continue to **remain** an issue of significant concern far into the future.
**(5b)** Health care costs will continue to **stay** an issue of significant concern far into the future.

**(6a)** If racism does **remain** a problem, how can conservatives object to remedying it?
**(6b)** If racism does **stay** a problem, how can conservatives object to remedying it?

**(7a)** The trade in illegal pesticides **remains** a problem in Bolivia.
**(7b)** The trade in illegal pesticides **stays** a problem in Bolivia.

Are my b-variants correct?
If not, then why not?
If they are, then what is the difference between a- and b-variants?

Comment: ***stay*** is "comprehensible" and I defy anyone to claim it's somehow "ungrammatical". But it isn't ***idiomatic*** for any of your examples (there's probably no meaningful *reason* for that, though). Stick with ***remain*** (or ***continue to be***)

Comment: Apart from the weather (_Hope it stays fine_), we tend not to use _stay_ for _continue to be a certain way_. (No particular reason - we just don't.)

Comment: Too many questions to answer. "stay a problem" is not idiomatic in English. stay and remain are not synonyms.